# lsblk + capture only the disks

Tags: linux, filesystems, disk, sfdisk, lsblk

I want to capture only the disks from **lsblk**

as showing here fd0 also appears in spite its not really disk for use

in this case we can just do **lsblk | grep disk | grep -v fd0**

but maybe we missed some other devices that need to filter them by **grep -v**

what other disk devices that could be appears from **lsblk | grep disk** and not really disks ?

```
lsblk | grep disk 

fd0                2:0    1     4K  0 disk
sda                8:0    0   100G  0 disk
sdb                8:16   0     2G  0 disk /Kol
sdc                8:32   0     2G  0 disk
sdd                8:48   0     2G  0 disk
sde                8:64   0     2G  0 disk
sdf                8:80   0     2G  0 disk


lsblk
NAME             MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
fd0                2:0    1     4K  0 disk
sda                8:0    0   150G  0 disk
├─sda1             8:1    0   500M  0 part /boot
└─sda2             8:2    0 149.5G  0 part
├─vg00-yv_root 253:0    0  19.6G  0 lvm  /
├─vg00-yv_swap 253:1    0  15.6G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
└─vg00-yv_var  253:2    0   100G  0 lvm  /var
sdb                8:16   0     2G  0 disk /Kol
sdc                8:32   0     2G  0 disk
sdd                8:48   0     2G  0 disk
sde                8:64   0     2G  0 disk
sdf                8:80   0     2G  0 disk
sr0               11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

Comment: fd0 is a  floppy disk, so it *is* a "disk". There may be nothing in it, but the device exists. Ditto for sr0. There may be SCSI or SATA disks that  are not mounted/ Are they to be included or not? IOW, the selection criteria have to be specified a bit more precisely.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want only disks identified as SCSI by the device major number `8`, without device partitions, you could search on device major rather than the string "disk":

```
lsblk -d | awk '/ 8:/'
```

where the `-d` (or `--no-deps`) option indicates to not include device partitions.

For reasonably recent linux systems, the simpler

```
lsblk -I 8 -d
```

should suffice, as noted by user Nick.

Comment: `lsblk -I 8 -d` works too.

Comment: @Nick: if `-I 8` is supported.  Looks like for GNU systems, it was introduced somewhere between coreutils 8.21 and 8.25.

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to get only the device names of all disks without any other output. Ended up using this:

```
lsblk -nd --output NAME
```

Which yields something like

```
sda
sdb
```

`-d` only outputs disks,
`-n` removes the header line,
and `--output NAME` make sure only the name of the device is listed.

Comment: Or the more succinct `lsblk -I 8 -ndo NAME` if you like that kind of thing.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have enough reputation to comment, so here's my comment as an answer.

```
sudo lsblk -I 8,259 -d
```

if you want to include `nvme` devices in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can show the internal kernel device name with:

```
lsblk -np --output KNAME
/dev/nvme0n1
/dev/nvme1n1
/dev/nvme0n1p1
/dev/nvme1n1p1
/dev/nvme0n1p2
/dev/nvme1n1p2
```

Answer (score 0):

Since no solutions works for me, I just used again `jq`...

```shellsession
$ lsblk  -d  -J | jq '.blockdevices[] | select(.type == "disk" and  .rm == false and .ro == false) | .name +" "+.size' -r
vda 70G
vdb 20G
```